# Why are the lines of one object darker than another behind another object of 50% opacity?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Weird opacity issue]

What you see here are two shapes in Illustrator, both on a different layer. They are overlapped by a third shape, a blue box with 50% opacity. Why are the lines of the top shape darker than the one on the bottom? It's a total mystery to me, I have got to have missed some setting somewhere, but where?
I copied the top shape from another file, and created the bottom shape manually. Other than that, they seem to be exactly the same in terms of fill, line fill, opacity, everything (except for the shape, of course).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They can't be *exactly* the same. There has to be a difference, for example the top shape uses a rich black and the bottom shape doesn't. Or the top shape is set to overprint and the bottom shape isn't. *Something* has to be different.

Comment: Are you able to upload the .ai file to somewhere like Dropbox?

Comment: Is one a stroked path and the other outlined with a fill?

Comment: I agree with Scott, but I don't think we'll be able to help you without additional information. If you can edit your question to include more details, perhaps we can get to the bottom of it

Comment: Unless you upload the said file, I don't think anyone can diagnose the 'problem'. Scott is correct.